# Morris-Thorne Metric Redshift Function

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, wormholes

Why is the Morris-Thorne metric sometimes written with a redshift function and sometimes without?

Here is the version with the redshift function.

$ds^2=-e^{2\Phi}dt^2+\frac{1}{1-\frac{b}{r}}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2$

Where $\Phi$ is the redshift function and $b(r)$ is the shaping function.

And the version without.

$ds^2=-dt^2+dl^2+(b_0^2+l^2)d\Omega^2$

In this one, $l$ is the proper radial coordinate and $b_0$ is the throat radius.

Comment: You should post a link to this metric, perhaps with and without the redshift factor

Comment: ...or simply write it down yourself

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the metrics now.

Comment: Those are just different metrics - the first one is basically the Schwarzschild metric. Where have you seen the claim that they're the same?

Comment: I first saw the second one in Catalogue of Spacetimes, and the first one is from various papers. They are both called the Morris-Thorne metric. I have assumed that the second one is a version of the first one except written with the proper radial coordinate, hence the difference in terms behind dl and dr. I guess the term inside parentheses in the second one is equal to r squared.